# mysql get or create object id function, need to do double select, why?

Tags: mysql, function, select

I want to write function that will check if object exists in database - return its id
or if not - create object and return its id.

So i create this code:

```
drop function if exists getAuthorId;

DELIMITER  //

CREATE FUNCTION getAuthorId(anonym varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8, ispublic tinyint(1))     RETURNS INT
   BEGIN
   DECLARE y INT;
   IF (SELECT id INTO y FROM library_author where library_author.slug = getSlug(anonym) limit 1) THEN

    **# Here is need to make second select, cause if I just return y - it will be empty 
    Why ??**

       SELECT id INTO y FROM library_author where library_author.slug = getSlug(anonym) limit 1;
   RETURN y;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO author set author.anonym = anonym, author.slug = getSlug(anonym), author.is_public = ispublic, author.date_created = CURDATE();
    RETURN last_insert_id();
END IF;
END // 

DELIMITER ;
```

Is it any method to use only one select request ?

Comment: What if you did the 'select id' before the if statement, then do the comparison and (possibly) return? Y is likely empty outside of the brackets for the if statement.

Comment: Can you provide some code, cause i don't get it (

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE y INT;  
SELECT id INTO y FROM library_author where library_author.slug = getSlug(anonym) limit 1;  
IF( !ISNULL( Y )) then return Y;
   else return 0;  
end if;
```

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'return Y;

Comment: `
    IF( !ISNULL( Y ))   return Y;
    ELSE    return 0;
    END IF;
`

still get the same error